# Keep default value after try parse fails

Tags: c#, .net, default

I have this code:

```
string myStr = "sdfs";
double myDouble = 3;
double.TryParse(myStr, out myDouble);
```

So the parse will fail, and also the value which I assigned to "myDouble" will change to 0.

Is there a nice way to keep that 3 default value, even if parse fails ? Without having an if clause like

```
if(!double.TryParse(myStr, out myDouble))
{
    myDouble = 3;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for brevity of code, which may cause it to be difficult to maintain, or easy-to-maintain code which could be re-used? Depending on how you define "a nice way", different options are available.

Comment: I am looking to keep the assigned value of "3" for example after the parse fails having as few lines of code as possibile, so something like easy to maintain and reuse.

Comment: In that case, it would be a good idea to write your own function to do that, much as SomeUser posted in their answer. The intricacies of it are hidden away and your assignment just needs to be something like `double myDouble = ParseAsDoubleOrDefault(myStr, 3)`. Of course, you would need to modify the proposed function to return the value instead of if the parse succeeded.

Comment: It was nice if this kind of functionality was already provided by the framework, something like an override call that can have this default option in case of failure...  For me adding so many lines of code only for setting a default will cause a disaproval, till now i am going more for @tphx solution

Comment: If you'd like to give the Microsoft team suggestions as to how the .NET languages can be enhanced, you could try [visualstudio.uservoice.com](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/31481-net). In the meantime, it's just something you're going to have to create yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions  @AndrewMorton !

Comment: And thank you all !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's still kind of an if clause but less lines. This works for me:

```
    string myStr = "sdfs";
    double myDouble = Double.TryParse(myStr, out myDouble) ? myDouble : 3;
```

Comment: It may work, but you should use a variable with a meaningful name instead of the "magic number" 3.

Answer (score 1):

Really the only way to do it is something like this:

```
string myStr = "sdfs";
double myDouble;
double myDoubleDefaultValue = 3;
if (!double.TryParse(myStr, out myDouble))
{
    myDouble = myDoubleDefaultValue;
}
```

The reason is that with an out variable, the method must assign a value before it completes.

Comment: That's really not much different from what the OP already suggested.

Comment: yes, but I was also adding an explanation as to why it assigns the value.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Magic numbers would be a separate topic.  Might as well complain about naming variables `myDouble` and `myStr`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I guess you can ignore my "straw man" example if you want, still say it's a separate topic from what is being asked.

Comment: An interesting (to me, at least) additional piece of context: the *runtime* has no concept of `out`; this is purely a restriction the compiler / language imposes (for very good reasons re definite assignment etc). If you were implementing the method in IL, you would be under no obligation to assign a value, and you would be free to inspect the incoming value at any point including before assigning to it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Posting the same code with the only difference `myDoubleDefaultValue` instead of `3` is not an improvement and not an answer. Comments are for this.